# Automatically delete a macro using texStudio

Tags: texstudio

Hi I would like to delete macros from a document.  For example

```
\reviewed{my text}
```

Became:

```
my text
```

I know that alt+del delete the macro word, but the `\{}` still remains, so I still have to manually get rid of them.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). I think the simplest solution would be `\renewcommand\reviewed[1]{#1}`. Otherwise you'll need to use regular expressions (which may be complicated depending on the complexity of what can be in that macro.

Comment: Yes, I read that solution before.  The problem is that I need to completely remove the macro word, not just its effect on the document. I basically use it to highlight text under revision,  but after the revision has been made, I do not need it anymore.  I might need to highlight new text, so it will be confusing if the macro word remains, or I will need to create macros like \revision1, \revision2, etc.

Comment: That is probably off topic for this site as that is more of a shell related issue. However, I would recommend you define a macro(s) such that `\review{}` is the case where you need to reivew and then change that to `\reviwed{}` when done. This is a simple replace every occurence of `\review{` with `\reviewed{`, That requires two macros. If you prever to do it in just one macro, then use `\review{}` for content that still needs to be reviwed and the starred variant `\review*{}` to denote that it has been reviewed.

Comment: Here is a macro that implements starred variant with `\usepackage{xparse}`: `\NewDocumentCommand{\review}{s +m}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{#2}{{\color{blue}#2}}}` where I have denoted the text that needs to be reviewed to be in blue.